# Vector space of functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Good morning, I'm trying to calculate this quotient vector space $C^1[-1, 1]/S$, when $S$ is the following subspace of the continuous and derivable functions in the closed interval $[-1,1]$. $S=\{f \in C^1[-1, 1]:f(-1) =f(1)\}$.

My work:

I want to find the equivalence class of a function $f(x)\in C^1[-1, 1]$. For this, I also consider the function $g(x)\in C^1[-1, 1]$ Then we will say that $f \sim g$ iff $f-g \in S$ but $(f-g)(x)\in S$ iff $(f-g)(-1)=(f-g)(1)$.

And from there I wonder what is the next step? In other words, what does this vector space represent?

From here I'm stuck, how to find the equivalence class of $f(x)$?, how do I construct in quotient? Any help is welcome. Thank you so much!

Comment: If I got your question right, you want to get some sort of understanding of this vector space, right? Some "image" or some you are more familiar with. Is that it? If it is, I would try to find an isomorphism between this space and some other you are more familiar with.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for your contribution, but I really want to build the space that I put in the post, then I could think about it. If you can help me with this space, I would be very grateful !!!

Comment: Hint: try to construct a surjective linear transformation over $\mathscr{C}^1 [-1,1]$ whose kernel is $S$.

Comment: What do you mean by "building", because it is already built, it is well defined, so there is really nothing else to do. I think what is tricking is really getting some sense of what this vector space is, and as I said, once we have an isomorphism from this space to a more familiar one, we can work the desired space as if it were the other, as @DonAntonio did in his answer.

Comment: @Arthur Actually my biggest question is how to find the equivalence class of a function $f(x)\in C^1[-1, 1]$?. That is what I want to know, so please request your help.

Comment: Let $f $ be an element of $\mathscr{C}^1[-1,1]$ an equivalence class in the quotient set is going to be of the following form $f+S= \{  f+g | g\in S \}$.

Comment: @Arthur That is the standard definition of equivalence class, but how is it defined? For example, what is the equivalence class of $f(x)=x^2$? note that $f(x)\in C^1[-1, 1]$ and $f(x)\in S$

Comment: @DanielaRondón Clearly $\;[x^2]=S\;$,  or in the quotient space: $\;[x^2]=\[0]=\;$ the neutral element.

Comment: @DonAntonio Mmm, sorry for the inconvenience, but for example what class of equivalence would be the following functions: $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=3x+1$??, note that $f,g\in C^1[-1, 1]$. Thanks!

Comment: For example, $\;[e^x]=[-e^{-x}]\;,\;\;[3x+1]=[3x]\;$ ...and each equivalence lcass has infinite representatives.

Comment: @DonAntonio Wow, am I quite curious how you find the representatives of each class, please can you explain me? How do you do for example with functions like $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$?

Comment: @DanielaRondón There is no "**the** representatives": for each class there are *infinite* functions that can be *a* representative of that class. For example, also $\;[e^x]=[\sinh x]\;$ , or **any** quadratic polynomial with linear coefficient equal to zero can be a representative of the class of $\;S\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for your contribution, but I think I have not explained enough about my question, I refer to that given an arbitrary function $f(x)\in C^1 [-1,1]$, then what would be its equivalence class $[f(x)]$ in the quotient?

Comment: @DonAntonio Excuse me, in my previous question I did not mean to define this set $f+S= \{  f+g | g\in S \}$ but to go much deeper in how the equivalence relation defines the class?.  How do you do for example with functions like $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$??

Comment: @DanielaRondón The equiv. class of $\;\sin x\;$ is simply $\;[\sin x]\;$ ...or $\;\sin x+S\;$ , in the quotient space. What else?! You seem to be expecting that each class will have a very nice, neat, special...or I don't know what, representative. What does "going deeper" mean in this context? For example, since cosine is an *even function*, we have that $\;\cos1=\cos(-1)\;$ and thus $\;[\cos x]=[0]=[1]=[-14.5]\;$ , because $\;\cos x\in S\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry for any inconvenience. That is to say that all even functions are in the neutral element class? And what about the odd functions? Thanks and excuse me.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\;\phi:C^1[-1,1]\to\Bbb R\;,\;\;\phi(f):=f(1)-f(-1)\;$ is a non-zero linear functional , and thus $\;C^1[-1,1]/S\cong\Bbb R\;$

Comment: ... because $\ker \phi = S$.

Comment: @lhf Yes, of course...did you try to help the OP? Because I think she may have gotten that.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to help the OP. You don't need any help...

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention, although I am not really familiar with the dual space nor the linear functionalities, I would like to please help me is by way of the classical construction of quotient space , through equivalence classes.